# Type Error: tuple indices must be integers, not str?

Tags: python, tree

I'm trying to parse a tree but I'm getting the following error. Type Error: tuple indices must be integers, not str?

```
def parseExpression(expression):
    nodeMap = dict()
    counter = 1
    node = ""
    retExp =""
    for char in expression:
        if char == '(' or char == ')' :
            if (len(node) > 0):
                nodeMap[str(counter)] = node;
                retExp += str(counter)
                counter +=1
            retExp += char
            node =""
        elif char == ' ': continue
        else :
            node += char
    return retExp,nodeMap

def printTree(tree, node, nodeMap):
    if node not in tree:
        return 
    print ('%s -> %s' % (nodeMap[node], ' '.join(nodeMap[child] for child in tree[node])) )
    for child in tree[node]:
        printTree(tree, child, nodeMap)

expression = " ( Root( SQ ( VBZ ) ( NP ( DT ) ( NN ) ) ( VP ( VB ) ( NP ( NN ) ) ) ))"
expression, nodeMap = parseExpression(expression)
tree = parseExpression(expression)
printTree(tree, tree[''][0], nodeMap)
```

Output :

```
Root -> SQ
SQ -> VBZ NP VP
NP -> DT NN
VP -> VB NP
NP -> NN
```

Can someone help debug this program, any help appreciated thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/refd.py", line 29, in <module>
    printTree(tree, tree[''][0], nodeMap)
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: in which line ? Can you post the entire error message ?

Comment: so you're getting an error here : printTree(tree, tree[''][0], nodeMap). What did you want to do here ?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to format the output I get for tree the way I showed the output.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the name tree is pointing to a tuple, so there would be no such thing as tree[''].
Was tree supposed to be pointing to a dictionary?

Comment: Yeah It was suppose to be a dict.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning two values, retExp,nodeMap. Therefore, tree holds a tuple (retExp,nodeMap).

I'm assuming you wanted to take a print the stuffs out of the dictionary, that's the second element in your tuple. so what you could do is:

```
t,tree = parseExpression(expression)
printTree(tree, tree[''][0], nodeMap)
```

But wait, that gives another error because there is nothing stored with the keye '' in that dictionary. So I decided to take a print of the dictionary, and this is what I saw :

```
{'10': '10', '1': '1', '3': '3', '2': '2', '5': '5', '4': '4', '7': '7', '6': '6', '9': '9', '8': '8'}
```

Not only there is no key '', all the entries contain themselves as value. This is not a tree you've got here.

Comment: I did not notice my fuction was messed up.

Comment: Also, your printTree gets into infinite recursion if you call it with a valid keye e.g., printTree(tree, tree['1'][0], nodeMap).